# Arduino controlled regulator circuit to control two Peltier devices,

Tags: arduino, thermal, peltier

I am needing to find an arduino controlled circuit that will control the temperature in a box enclosure utilizing peltier devices.

So far, I have a SR7021 temperature sensor wired to an Arduino Nano via I2c. What I have envisioned is a Peltier device for cooling the box with another Peltier device heating the box.

At the programmed temperature both Peliter devices would have a low voltage applied , in effect cancelling each other out. When the temperature rises, the voltage to the cooling Peltier would rise and the voltage to the heating device would drop and vice versa when the temp drops.

The solution can utilize two circuits each driven by separate pins on the Arduino but ideally a single circuit with two controlled drivers for the Peltiers. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank-you,

Rick

Comment: I'm confused, what's wrong with a single Peltier device?

Comment: Most peltier devices can be driven in reverse, so as @unit128_t pointed out, using 1 for heating & another for cooling seems unnecessary & redundant. Also, wouldn't this question fit better on the arduino SE site (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: One reason behind using dual Peltier is to extend the life of the devices. The other is to enable the devices to make smaller changes in temperature to create a more stable environment.

Comment: "Also, wouldn't this question fit better on the arduino SE site (arduino.stackexchange.com)?" Not sure, although the circuit will be controlled by an arduino, it's the circuit itself I need help with. A circuit with two voltage outputs, if ouput A increases 1 watt, output B decreases by one watt.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have a PWM kr DAC pin free on your 'duino, you could use something like this I think:
[image]